# JSch Key authentification exception Auth fail

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, private-key

I get an exception *Auth fail* when I want to run this code block:

```
String remoteHostUserName = "me";
String remoteHostName = "xx.xxx.x.xx";
int port = 22;
String key = "/home/me/.ssh/id_rsa";

String deployPath = "/home/me/Schreibtisch/ssh_example";
JSch jsch=new JSch();

//creating the identity
jsch.addIdentity(key);
System.out.println("identity added ");

Session session=jsch.getSession(remoteHostUserName, remoteHostName, port);
System.out.println("session created.");
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();
```

I don't want to set a phrase.

Here the `ls -l` of the `.ssh` folder:

```
drwxrwx---  2 root    me  4096 Jul 27 16:01 .ssh
```

and finally the long list within the `.ssh` folder:

```
-rwxrw---- 1 root me  416 Jul 27 15:51 authorized_keys
-rwxrw---- 1 root me 1675 Jul 27 15:49 id_rsa
-rwxrw---- 1 root me  416 Jul 27 15:49 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root me  222 Jul 27 16:01 known_hosts
```

I copied the `.pub` file and renamed it `authorized_keys`.

I also added a logger here is the result:

```
INFO: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
INFO: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT sent
INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
INFO: ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
WARN: Permanently added 'xx.xxx.x.xx' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
INFO: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: publickey
INFO: Authentications that can continue: password
INFO: Next authentication method: password
INFO: Disconnecting from xx.xxx.x.xx port 22
Exception in thread "main" com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:512)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
at SSHTestStandAlone.testConnection(SSHTestStandAlone.java:33)
at SSHTestStandAlone.main(SSHTestStandAlone.java:11)
```

I think after the key authentication JSch want the normal password?

Here the output of the ssh -v command in the shell:

Here the output of the ssh -v command:

```
florian@florian-HP-EliteBook-8540w:~$ ssh -v florian@xx.xxx.x.xx
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xx.xxx.x.xx [xx.xxx.x.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/florian/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/florian/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/florian/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/florian/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/florian/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/florian/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
The authenticity of host 'xx.xxx.xx.x (xx.xxx.x.xx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'xx.xxx.x.xx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/florian/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/florian/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/florian/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Thank you very much and kind regards,
SirSandmann

Answer (score 2):

The `.ssh` folder and the `authorized_keys` file cannot be writtable by anyone except you.

Make sure you do

```
chmod 700 .ssh
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

---

Side note (unrelated to the problem):

Your private key cannot be readable by anyone else, but you. You compromise your security this way.

Also note that you do not need your private key, that you connect with to the server, in the server's `~/.ssh` folder.

---

Next time, test the authentication using a GUI client first, to check if your have it setup correctly.